# How can i get original nsdata of uiimage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

In my app, user can select a pic from album or camera where i can get uiimage representation. Since the album may have pic from web, the file type is not only jpg. Then i need to sent it to the server without convertion. Here i can only use nsdata.

I know UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation, but i think this two method may convert the original image. Maybe when quality set to 1 UIImageJPEGRepresentation can get original pic?

Is there any method to get the original uiimage nsdata?

Comment: As far as I know, the pictures in the camera roll are stored in JPEG format (at least that's what I see after SSHing the device and checking the files). So the JPEGrepresentation would work in your case

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu: Many apps have a feature "Store in Photo Album", and that works also with TIFF, BMP and maybe some other file types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ALAssetsLibrary` and `ALAssetRepresentation` to get the original data. Example:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSUInteger size = repr.size;
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:size];
        NSError *error;
        [repr getBytes:data.mutableBytes fromOffset:0 length:size error:&error];
            /* Now data contains the image data, if no error occurred */
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        /* handle error */
    }];
}
```

But there are some things to consider:

- `assetForURL:` works asynchronously.
- On the device, using `assetForURL:` will cause a confirmation dialog, which might be irritating the user:

> "Your App" would like to use your current location. This allows access
>   to location information in photos and videos.

- If the user denies access, `assetForURL:` calls the failure block.
- The next time you use this method, `assetForURL:` will fail without asking the user again. Only if you reset the location warnings in System Settings, the user is asked again.

So you should be prepared that this method fails and use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` as a fallback. But in that case you will not get the original data, e.g. the metadata (EXIF etc.) are missing.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't noticed yet imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo: has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 8.0+ use PHImageManager.default().requestImageData() after you locate the corresponding asset in the assets (you can get to assets with PHAsset.fetchAssets().

See more info and example code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41589063/2650588) to very similar question [How to upload image that was taken from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138484/how-to-upload-image-that-was-taken-from-uiimagepickercontroller).