# How to upload image that was taken from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, asihttprequest

After user choose image from the iPhone library with `UIImagePickerController`, I want to upload it to my server using `ASIHTTPRequest` library.

I know that with `ASIHTTPRequest` I can upload a file with the file's URl, but how do I get the image URL?

I know I can get the image `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`, that look like this:

```
"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F2829B2E-6C6B-4569-932E-7DB03FBF7763&ext=JPG"
```

is this the URL I need to use?

Comment: convert image into NSData and then upload it

Comment: thanks but I know it's possible to upload directly from filesystem, and I prefer to do it like this

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121204/how-can-i-get-original-nsdata-of-uiimage/12121605#12121605

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

Comment: "is this the URL I need to use?" Does it work when you use that URL?

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of answers that suggest UIImageJPEGRepresentation or UIImagePNGRepresentation. But these solutions will convert the original file while this question is actually about saving the file AS IS.

It looks like uploading the file directly from assets library is impossible. But it can be accessed using PHImageManager to get the actual image data. Here's how:

**Swift 3** (Xcode 8, only for iOS 8.0 and higher)

1) Import the Photos framework

```
import Photos
```

2) In the imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) get the asset URL

3) Fetch assets using fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:)

4) Get the actual image data with requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:). In the result handler of this method you will have the data as well as URL to the file (the URL can be accessed on Simulator, but unfortunately is not accessible on the device - in my tests startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() always returned false). However this URL is still useful to find out the file name.

Example code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let assetURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL,
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetURL], options: nil).firstObject,
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first,
        let targetURL = Foundation.URL(string: "file://\(documentsPath)") {

        PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data, UTI, _, info) in
            if let imageURL = info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? URL,
                   imageData = data {
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: targetURL.appendingPathComponent(imageURL.lastPathComponent), options: .atomic)

                        self.proceedWithUploadFromPath(targetPath: targetURL.appendingPathComponent(imageURL.lastPathComponent))

                   } catch { print(error) }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This will give you the file AS IS including its correct name and you can even get its UTI to determine correct mimetype (in addition to determining it via file extension) while preparing multipart body for upload.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is deprecated :(

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways

**1:**

You can upload the image using the **imagePickerController** delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{   

    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //Upload your image
}
```

**2:**

You can save the picked image url and upload later using this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
    //Save the imageUrl
}

-(void)UploadTheImage:(NSString *)imageUrl{

 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageUrl];
 typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
 typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    

 ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){

  ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
  CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
  UIImage *myImage = nil;   

  if (ref) {
      myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];

        //upload the image   
     }      
  };      

  ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror){

  };          


  ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
 [assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:result block failureBlock:failureblock];
```

}

**Notes:** Please make sure the scope of `ALAssetsLibrary` object while using ARC.Better to use the `ALAssetsLibrary` object as a singleton.

Comment: The ALAssetsLibrary way will (I believe) result in the app requesting location permissions from the user, which is not ideal - the first way avoids this.

Comment: Is there a reason we store the url as a string just to inflate it back later? Is it more expensive to store a url?

Comment: ALAssetRepresentation is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Save the photo in Document directory and use that url to upload.For example

```
NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

upload this image as `[request setFile:jpgPath forKey:@"image"]`;

Answer (score 1):

To get the image UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUR. This Sample Code is given below

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        NSString *fileName = [representation filename];
        NSLog(@"fileName : %@",fileName);

        CGImageRef ref = [representation fullResolutionImage];
        ALAssetOrientation orientation = [[myasset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];

    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL 
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:nil];

}
```

NOTE: It works only in **iOS 5** and later.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is

Step 1:  Get path for DocumentsDirectory

```
func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    return documentsFolderPath.appendingPathComponent(filename)
}
```

Step 2:  Save at the path with tempFileName

```
 func saveImage(image: UIImage, path: String ) {
    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    do {
        try pngImageData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Step 3:  Usage  in  imagePickerController function

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){

    if var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {// image asset

    self.saveImage(image: image, path: fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: "temp_dummy_image.png"))

}
```

Step 4 : To get the image when required

get the reference like this

let localfilepath = self.fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: "temp_dummy_image.png")

Step 5: After using the image, to trash the temp image

```
func removeTempDummyImagefileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
    let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path

    do {
        if let documentPath = documentsPath
        {
            let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(documentPath)")
            print("all files in cache: \(fileNames)")
            for fileName in fileNames {

                if (fileName.hasSuffix(".png"))
                {
                    let filePathName = "\(documentPath)/\(fileName)"
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePathName)
                }
            }

            let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(documentPath)")
            print("all files in cache after deleting images: \(files)")
        }

    } catch {
        print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can upload image by creating form try below code**

```
-(void)UploadImage{

NSString *urlString = @"yourUrl";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// file
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:[selectedImageObj]],90);


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"user_photo\"; filename=\"photoes.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",@"ImageNmae"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];
//return and test
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  }
```